# Getting other fields during a Drupal Services GET

Tags: 7, services

I made the following request via GET: api/node?fields=nid,title,field_media

But I'm getting the errror: **Invalid query provided, double check that the fields and parameters you defined are correct and exist. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.field_media' in 'field list'**

I'm assuming its only looking at the node table, but how do you make it grab all the fields of this content type?

I couldn't easily find the documentation of these endpoints and how to call them properly. How is everyone figuring this out?

[image]

Comment: From my understanding the Entity Index resources can only return base fields, i.e. node id, title, language, status, etc, it (sadly) cannot return fields. I agree this sucks. Here's my old attempt at a workaround for this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2601764

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here. So it looks like it can only return exactly what we see in the columns in the **node** table and none of the fields?

Comment: Correct. I'm open to a patch that allows other fields to be included in the results though, that'd be much cleaner and more efficient than just delivering the whole node.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) or [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_json) and create a page view that contains your fields in JSON, or XML, or whatever you want to use. Then simply do a `GET` to your view's URL.

Comment: what about making a post to update or add to these fields in the same content type using services?

Comment: @duckx `POST` is a totally diff animal than `GET`. My answer here will solve your `GET` problem. Since this question is about `GET` the answer should only be about `GET`.